# Vue.js 3 input showing data not change when watch change the value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I have a `TextInput` component and based on [Vue docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#usage-with-v-model), I added `v-model` to my component.

It is my component:

```js
<template>
    <div class="floating_input">
        <input type="text" :id="id" :name="name" :key="id" class="form_input"
               :placeholder="label" v-model="value">
        <label class="floating_label" :for="id">{{ label }}</label>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
    import { defineProps, defineEmits, computed } from "vue";

    const props = defineProps({
        label: {
            type: String,
            required: false
        },
        id: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        modelValue: String
    });
    const emit = defineEmits(['update:modelValue']);
    
    const value = computed({
        get() {
            return props.modelValue
        },
        set(value) {
            emit('update:modelValue', value)
        }
    })
</script>
```

In another component, I use a watcher to check that if the value is not numeric, use the `oldValue` as the value of this component.
Finally, when I enter a letter, everything is correct and the `oldValue` is considered as the `currentValue`, but the displayed value is wrong and shows the letters too.

It is what shows in Vue dev tools:
[image: vue dev tools]

and it is what shows in the browser
[image: Browser]

Answer (score 0):

Why watch for the value, and not use built-it functionality?

```html
...
<input type="number" v-model.number="value">
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But there are several filters in addition to the number on the input, and I also have to check if the numeric character is Persian, chenge it to English. The solution was that I had to change the value in the next tick.